# How to convert a var[] into a bidimensional var

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, jsp

It is a very complicated and convoluted to explain, anyway, I'll try to explain my problem. I've the following script in a JSP page:

```
<script>
     var matrix = [];
     <% String lengthStr = (configuration.getLength())+(configuration.getWidth());

     //configuration is an object that is passed as a parameter to the JSP, including information about the size.

     int length = Integer.parseInt(lengthStr); %>
     for (var i = 0; i < <%= length %>; i++) {
        matrix.push(0);
     }
     // set the hidden field on init
     $('#matrix').val(JSON.stringify(matrix));
     $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(evt) {
                    var me = $(this);
                    var idx = +me.attr('id'); // the + sign turns this value to a number
                    if (matrix[idx] === 0) {
                        matrix[idx] = 1;
                        me.addClass('AreaBlocked');
                    } else {
                        matrix[idx] = 0;
                        me.removeClass('AreaBlocked');
                    }
                // update the hidden field every time a user clicks something
                $('#matrix').val(JSON.stringify(matrix));
      });
</script>
```

This script creates a one-dimensional vector, which associates for each position the id of a button. Each time a button is pressed, it changes color and the value of the location (in the array "matrix") corresponding to the button is changed. If the button is pressed again, it is restored.

This is the part relating to the generation of buttons:

```
<table>
                <%
                    int length= Integer.parseInt(configuration.getLength());
                    int width= Integer.parseInt(configuration.getWidth());

                   for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++){

                       String iChar = Integer.toString(i);
                       %>
                       <tr>
                       <%    
                       for(int j = 1; j <= width; j++){
                           String jChar = Integer.toString(j);
                           String idChar = iChar+jChar;
                       %>
                       <td><input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="<%=idChar %>"></td>
                      <%
                       }
                      %>
                      </tr>
                      <%
                   }
                %>
                </table>

                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="MyButton">
                <input type="hidden" id="matrix" name="matrix" value="" />
```

Every time you press a button, the value in the "id" location of matrix is changed; when I press the "continue" submit button, the var "matrix" is sent to a servlet and converted into an int [] array with an object Gson.
**Now the real question is**: Could I use a two-dimensional array instead of a one-dimensional vector, maintaining the logic of the algorithm? If possible, could you share me the code with changes necessary for this purpose?

Comment: You just need code for generating a 2 dimensional array ?

Comment: Shouldn't this `(configuration.getLength())+(configuration.getWidth())` line be a multiplication instead of addition ?

Comment: @11thdimension No, because each button must have a different id from each other button. Example, the button row "9", column "2" has id="92"; the button in row "2", column "9" has id="29" If I perform a multiplication with the two buttons in the example, they would have the same id and in the database I'll have conflicts with the primary key.

Comment: What I need is to replace the one-dimensional array in my code with a two-dimensional array, reproducing the same results that I make in the script

For example, when I press the button in row "1", column "1", I'm going to change the 11th position of the var, which is corresponding to the id of the button pressed. Having to use a two-dimensional array, when I press the button in row "1" and column "1", I'm going to change the array in position "array [1] [1]". I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript Arrays are [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Meaning they're collection of (key, value) pairs.

so if you define an array `mat=[]` an then assign it's first element `mat[0]=[]` it becomes a 2D array with 1 row and 0 columns.

You can add as many rows you need and there's no restriction on rows to be of same length.

Following is the code to get 2D matrix given of given dimensions. `convert1Dto2D` converts 1D array to 2D array.

```js
function get2DArray(row, col) {
    var mat;
    row = +row;
    col = +col;

    if( isNaN(row) || isNaN(col) || row < 0 || col < 0) {
        mat == undefined;
    }
    if(row == 0) {
    }
    mat = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        mat[i] = [];
        mat[i].length = col;
    }

    return mat;
}

function convert1Dto2D(arr, row, col) {
    var mat = get2DArray(row,col);
    var matI = 0; matJ = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        matI = Math.floor(i/col);
        matJ = Math.floor(i%col);
        console.log(i + " : " + matI + " : "+  matJ);
        mat[matI][matJ] = arr[i];
    }
    return mat;
}
```